# Would a GPU make the applications in the virtual machine faster?

Tags: virtual-machine, performance, qemu, gpu

I installed Windows on a virtual machine which runs through KVM/QEMU. The virtual machine is hosted on a Debian server which has just a basic GPU on the motherboard.

Applications which rely on GPU, such as Adobe Premiere Pro, don't run fast enough on this virtual machine. [The Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU/Guest_graphics_acceleration) on the subject explains the techniques which allow to obtain bare-metal experience, but I'm not ready yet to try them, so I'm stuck with QXL/SPICE for now.

Suppose I put a dedicated GPU in the server. Would it automatically (with no configuration changes) make the applications which rely on the GPU run faster? Or it will have absolutely no effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatically - no, not at all.

Manually via PCI(e) passthrough in case your system supports IOMMU **and** AMD-Vi/Intel VT-d:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#Plain_QEMU_without_libvirt

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GPU_passthrough_with_libvirt_qemu_kvm